# Python test explorer not recognizing test in VS Code when test files split into multiple files

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I have BaseTestCase in the same file as my test VS code Test explorer is able to identity my test.

[Sample Code](https://github.com/tkumark/pytestproject)

[image]

Folder structure

```
MyProject/
   app/
   test/
       myworking_test.py
       base.py
       mynotworking_test.py
```

**myworking_test.py** This one works and able to identify by VS code Explorer

```
import unittest

class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.num = 1
    def tearDown(self):
        self.num = None

class MyTest(BaseTestCase):
    def runTest(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.num, 1)
```

If I split this into 2 file where BaseTestCase is another file and test in another file then how do I configure it.

**base.py**

```
import unittest

class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.num = 1
    def tearDown(self):
        self.num = None
```

**mynotworking_test.py**

```
from test.base import BaseTestCase

class MyTest(BaseTestCase):
    def runTest(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.num, 1)
```

**Updated based on suggestion given below:**

As you can see it is giving unresolved import base. The same goes for when using just "import base"
[image: Error when getting unresolved import base]

Comment: what is the location of these files? read about python `import` statement.

Comment: @rioV8 I have updated above discription please check. I think I have fixed the import statement but still not working up in the test explorer.

Comment: @rioV8 I have also updated sample code in the question discription.

Comment: why do you have `__pycache__` in your repo? It is generated stuff.

Comment: ya i did not add a gitignore so that file go added.

Comment: you don't need to all modified files to the index, you can **add** individual files and you can remove files from the index

Answer (score 0):

The files are in the same directory so instead try

```
import base
k = base.BaseTestCase()

class MyTest(k):
```

Comment: I tired but does not seem to work. I have updated the question above with sample code. Please have a look and see where I am going wrong.

Comment: import base line gives warning unresolved import base. also I have updated screen shot

Comment: @kumar like I said before the unresolved import error is due to the two files being in the same directory to fix them just remove test.base and use import base instead

Comment: Sorry I did not write clearly last time. I do not get any error but VS code test explorer does not show the test on the left pane when i use "from test.base import BaseTestCase". when I use "import base" I get unresoled import error. If you have the time please have look the github sample code

Answer (score 0):

```python
from base import BaseTestCase

class MyTest(BaseTestCase):
    def runTest(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.num, 1)
```

or

```python
import base

class MyTest(base.BaseTestCase):
    def runTest(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.num, 1)
```

---

**Edit 1**

If I run the example code the problem seems to be the file name: **`base.py`**

I get a lot of compiler warnings.

Any other name but **base** is ok.

With the following files I have it working

**base_test.py**

```python
import unittest

class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.num = 1
    def tearDown(self):
        self.num = None
```

**mynowworking_test.py**

```python
from test.base_test import BaseTestCase

class MyTest(BaseTestCase):
    def runTest(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.num, 1)
```

or

```python
import test.base_test

class MyTest(test.base_test.BaseTestCase):
    def runTest(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.num, 1)
```

---

**Edit 2**

I renamed `base_test.py` to `base.py`.

Change the import to:

```
from test.base import BaseTestCase
```

```
import test.base
```

I still have the errors in the `Problem` panel but the tests work.

I close VSC and start it again.

Now the `Problem` panel does not show errors in `base.py` and the tests work.

It looks like I have the original files from the repo back and it works.

But it did not run the first time I opened the project.

Comment: This does not seem to work. I updated the screen shot. You can have a look at the github sample code given above if it helps.

Comment: @kumar I have a working version, tried with Python 3.6

Comment: When you say working version is it based off of my sample code from github https://github.com/tkumark/pytestproject or your own project ? I am sure I am missing something silly. If you do not mind share your code?

Comment: @kumar I renamed a few files from the repo files, the **not** does not apply anymore because the test works

Comment: When you say renamed a few files. what you changed so I can do similar changes to see what I have done wrong

Comment: after making the recomended changes does test showup in the test explorer?

Comment: @kumar Apply the changes I made in **Edit 1**. Use the named files. Then try **Edit 2**

Comment: @kumar From the test runner in the sidebar

Comment: are you using window or ubuntu? it not showing the sidebar I have done the same changes